# The database is not connected. What can it be connected with?

Tags: mysql, exception, intellij-idea, ide

**I can't connect to the database. What can it be connected with?**

[image]

> Connection to carshop@localhost failed.         [08001] Could not create
>   connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

Comment: Is MySQL server actually started

Comment: @RiggsFolly the database seems to work

Comment: Can you connect to the database? Is it on the correct port?

Comment: @vikingsteve in workbench works

Comment: Please check if there are additional errors in idea.log ("Help | Show log in..."). Do you use any antivirus software or firewall?

Comment: @y.bedrov https://gist.github.com/ilya-yarets/ade31b4cee3e96044fa6f59f4844410d . i am using BitDefender antivirus

Comment: Please check the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7727

Comment: @y.bedrov thank you. please, you can form answer or give this link in answer below. And I will do your answer the best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible workarounds:

- In DataSource configuration window go to Advanced tab and set serverTimezone property to UTC.
- Or switch DataSource driver to MySQL Connector/J for 5.1 (my version is 5.1.46)

Related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-7727